# JQuery Droppable and Draggable between listviews - No sorting within listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am developing a mobile application using cordova, jquery mobile and touch punch. I have two listviews similar to the example: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists with code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

However, I do not want the lists to be sortable within themselves, as this interferes with scrolling if the user swipes up and down the list. Both lists can get very long. As such, I want to prevent sorting within the ul, but retain the draggable and droppable properties. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include example code in your question and not behind a link, if possible.

Comment: Updated as requested..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 $(function() {
   $("#list1 li, #list2 li").draggable({
     helper: "clone"
   });
   $("#list1, #list2").droppable({
     drop: function(ev, ui) {
       $(this).append(ui.draggable);
     }
   });
 });
```

[**Online demo(jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/6k0hre67/)

Comment: Thanks. However, I am still able to sort both lists within themselves, i.e., I can move item 1 after item 4 in the lists themselves. I want to have the sorting disabled.

Comment: @Nasheia You want to have `draggable` that it allows to user to drag items to anywhere and prevent user to sort items. These two things are contradictory and you can't do them together.

Comment: Therefore draggable and droppable cannot work without sortable?

Comment: @Nasheia In this case they can’t. I think you need get more information about jQuery-UI sortable. It’s different with sortable in general cases.

Comment: Is it possible to use touch moves to prevent sorting in the same listbox?